# Enqueuing a stylesheet and ensuring it's loaded before (not after) the theme's stylesheet

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

In `wp_enqueue_style()`'s doc I see the third parameter is for stylesheets to be loaded before the one called by the function.

But is it possible to do the contrary, meaning to instruct WP to load a stylesheet *before* the theme's stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, themes usually almost always enqueue scripts and style via the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook with default priority set in add action. This is the [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) statement by default

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_styles_and_scripts' );
```

As you can see, a priority is not set in the action, which means that it will default to `10`.

With this in mind, you can use a priority of less than `10` to load your styles and scripts earlier than the theme, keeping in mind, the `$deps` parameters should not be set when you enqueue and/or register your styles and scripts

### FEW NOTES

- If no priority is set in either plugin or themes, and a styles or scripts is loaded from a child theme or plugin, the plugin style/script will load first, then those in the child theme and then the main (parent) theme's styles and scripts. This is the order in which functions load by default
- Within the same function, styles and scripts are loaded in the order they appear inside the function, so the style/script appearing first will load first. Again being said, that is if the `$deps` parameters aren't set.

Comment: You meant "wp_enqueue_style" right?

Comment: No specially talked about the hook here :-). `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is used to hook the function in which you register styles (via `wp_enqueue_style() function) and scripts (via the `wp_register_script()` function. Sometimes the naming conventions used in Wordpress can be quite confusing